# use 'localhost:8000' would send cookie but '127.0.0.1:8000' won't?

Tags: cookies, cors

I have an django server running at localhost:8000, whitelisting localhost:3000 for CORS and allow credentials. At same time react app is running at localhost:3000.

I found that if react is calling django's apis using 127.0.0.1:8000, then it wont set the cookies in the request, even if i set allow-credential to be true.  (server still accepts the request, no CORS error either)

```
export const httpPatch = (url: string, data: any): Promise<any> =>
         axios
           .patch(url, data, { withCredentials: true })
           .then(({ data }) => toCamelCase(data));
```

but `localhost:8000` works fine, sets the cookie, no CORS either. anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is a different origin than `localhost`, so it would not share the set of cookies. Cookies are bound to a single origin.

Comment: hmm even if localhost's ip address is 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Yes. ip addresses can serve many domains, and they will all be treated as separate origins.